# Does the triviality of the orthonormal frame bundle imply the triviality of the spin bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be a space and time orientable spin semi-Riemannian manifold of signature $(p,q)$, ${\rm Fr}(M)$ be its bundle of space and time oriented pseudo-orthonormal frames, $\Lambda : P\rightarrow {\rm Fr}(M)$ be the covering by the ${\rm Spin}(p,q)$-principal bundle $P$ given by a spin structure. I am trying to prove that if $M$ is metric parallelizable, then $P\rightarrow M$ must be trivial. I think it is true from an indirect argument with the additional assumption that the number of spin structures is finite.

What I tried is this: let $e$ be a global section of ${\rm Fr}(M)$. There exists a lift $\tilde e$ to $P$ iff $e_*(\pi_1(M))\subset \Lambda_*(\pi_1(P))$, and I'm basically stuck there. I tried the long exact sequence of homotopy groups, but it didn't help. I would appreciate any help, or a counter-example if I am mistaken.

Comment: To me this looks like a question more suitable for mathoverflow. Ie research level maths, but maybe you can get an answer here as well.

Comment: Spin structures are affine over $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, the set of double covers of $M$. If one spin structure is trivial, *the rest are nontrivial*. All you can say is that if $\text{Fr}(M)$ is trivial, *there exists a trivial spin structure*.

Comment: Mike : thanks. What you say in your comment seems very reasonable to me. Perhaps you could elaborate a little bit and post it as an answer ?

Comment: I would like to find a statement of this fact in Lawson and Michelson's book on spin geometry, which I do not have on hand this morning. So I hope to write an answer later in the day. But I warn that I am chronically very slow at turning comments into answers.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the set of spin structures on an $SO(n)$-bundle $E$ is either empty, or is affine over $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, which may be identified with the set of double covers of $M$ (that is, principal $\Bbb Z/2$-bundles over $M$). This is proved as Theorem 2.1.7 in Lawson and Michelsohn's book "Spin geometry"; this only discusses the case of definite characteristic. In particular, this implies that the spin structure is unique if $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) = 0$, and is non-unique otherwise. If two spin structures are both trivializable, then they are in particular isomorphic, so the answer to your question is: $E$ is trivial implies any spin structure on $E$ is trivializable if, and only if, $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) = 0$.

The proof of this runs through a certain short exact sequence coming from the Serre spectral sequence (their formula 2.1.4). I will not discuss this precisely here, but the following discusses how to change their argument so that it remains true (without mentioning the details).

Their argument works without *much* change for $\text{Spin}(p,q)$, which you'll recall is a double cover of $SO^+(p,q)$ (which deformation retracts onto $SO(p) \times SO(q)$.)  Unfortunately, they relied on the statement

> The spin structures on $E$ are in natural one-to-one correspondence with 2-sheeted coverings of $P_{SO}(E)$ which are non-trivial on the fibers of $\pi$.

Here $P_{SO}(E)$ is the corresponding principal $SO(n)$-bundle to the oriented vector bundle $E$. Because $SO^+(p,q)$ has *three* inequivalent non-trivial double covers when $p,q \geq 2$, this definition will no longer apply. Instead, one should say

> The spin structures on $E$ are in natural one-to-one correspondence with 2-sheeted coverings of $P_{SO}(E)$ which restrict to the standard covering of $SO^+(p,q)$ on each fiber of $\pi$.

Here the "standard double cover" is the double cover $\text{Spin}(p,q) \to SO^+(p,q)$. You can identify it by using the fact that $$H^1(SO^+(p,q);\Bbb Z/2) = H^1(SO(p);\Bbb Z/2) \times H^1(SO(q);\Bbb Z/2),$$ and demand that the corresponding cohomology class should restrict to the standard generator of each factor (which is the unique non-trivial element when $p,q \geq 2$, but is just zero when $p = 1$ or $q = 1$).

This now pins down a specific cohomology class in $H^1(SO^+(p,q);\Bbb Z/2)$ (said differently, a specific double covering) that your double cover should restrict to on each fiber. And from here the argument proceeds as expected; in fact, the following statement is true for any $p,q$; we do not need to demand $p,q \geq 2$.

> Let $P$ be a principal $\text{SO}^+(p,q)$-bundle. Then if $P$ admits any spin structure, that spin structure provides a bijection between the set of spin structures on $P$ with the set $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$. In particular, a trivial bundle has $|H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)|$-many spin structures, and so carries $|H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)| - 1$ non-trivial spin structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have a problem with your argument that two trivializable spin structures are isomorphic. They are isomorphic as bundles, but not necessarily as spin structures. There is an example p 84 of the same book.

Comment: @FabienBesnard 1) When I say "trivializable spin structure", I do not mean trivializable principal bundle; I mean that given the trivialization $Q/\pm \cong M \times SO$, there is an isomorphism $Q \cong M \times \text{Spin}$ whose quotient is the identity. 2) The remark you are referencing says that $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$ classifies spin structures on a vector bundle, while a certain quotient of this group classifies isomorphism classes of $\text{Spin}$-principal bundles which ignore the structure of the quotient. The latter is what you are worried about in your comment.

Comment: I should add that my argument is quite silly: all I really mean to say is that when we say spin structures (on a spinnable v.b.) are affine over $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, this means that the set of spin structures is in bijection with the set $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$; when we say 'spin structures', we mean what you care about, not isomorphism classes of abstract principal bundles.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the problem is with my question: when I ask if $P\rightarrow M$ is trivial, I mean "as vector bundle". The idea I have is that the different classes of spin structures are all represented by trivial bundles. I think the example in Lawson and Michelson goes in that direction.

Comment: @FabienBesnard ok, then instead the discussion of remark 1.14 gives the complete answer to your question. They discuss the classification of Spin bundles with given reduction - they are classified by $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/2)/\delta^0(H^0(X;SO_{p,q}))$, where now we are pulling back the standard generator of $H^1(SO_{p,q};\Bbb Z/2)$. They then give many examples where this group is zero, but there's no reason to believe it is always zero for any vector bundle, and the frame bundle does not always fall into the two cases they give for which this group is always trivial.

Comment: I am not inclined to spend time looking for an example of a frame bundle specifically for which this new question fails.