# If the bundle of orthonormal frames has a continuos/smooth global section will the bundle of spin frames also have one?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold with metric of signature $(p,q)$. I believe the signature of the metric is not relevant for this discussion so I leave it arbitrary (corrections to this are highly appreciated!).

Now let $\xi = (F(M),\pi,M,{\rm SO}(p,q))$ be the principal bundle of orthonormal frames over $M$. Suppose that $M$ admits a spin structure and that $\zeta = (P,\pi_P,M,{\rm Spin}(p,q))$ is the associated principal bundle of spin frames and $\Phi:P\to F(M)$ is the principal map obeying $\Phi(p\cdot g)=\Phi(p)\cdot \rho(g)$ where $\rho: {\rm Spin}(p,q)\to {\rm SO}(p,q)$ is the covering map and where the $\cdot$ is the right $G$-action on both $P$ and $F(M)$.

Now it is clear that if the spin frame bundle $\zeta$ admits a global section $\sigma:M\to P$ then so does $\xi$. In fact $\Phi\circ \sigma : M\to F(M)$, it is a section because $\Phi$ is a fiber bundle morphism. Moreover if $\sigma$ is a smooth section, assuming $\Phi$ to be smooth, so will be $\Phi\circ\sigma$.

Now my question is about the converse. If the orthonormal frame bundle $\xi$ admits a global section $E:M\to F(M)$ can we prove that the bundle of spin frames $\zeta$ will also have a global section? Obviously we would like to define $\sigma:M\to P$ by $$\Phi(\sigma(x))=E(x),\tag{1}$$

but the issue is that $\Phi$ is not injective. In fact it is $2$-$1$. In that setting for each $x\in M$ there are two possible solutions for $\sigma(x)$ via (1). We can clearly pick one of such solutions at each point and indeed construct a map $\sigma:M\to P$ with $\pi_P\circ \sigma= \operatorname{id}_M$ but can we do so in order that the resulting $\sigma$ is continuous or smooth?

I have the intuition that the answer is yes and that it is *very basic* and I'm missing it, but I really don't know how to argue this rigorously.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112500/does-the-triviality-of-the-orthonormal-frame-bundle-imply-the-triviality-of-the
should answer your question

Comment: That's exactly the same question. Thanks @GFR, I'm deleting this one since it is a duplicate.

Comment: Although the answer in the linked question does not seem to address your question. You are asking about the triviality of the underlying bundle, rather than the triviality of the spin structure. Or is this not your question?

Comment: Hi @Tyrone, I must admit that I'm confused. I thought that "triviality of the spin structure" meant just "triviality of the underlying spin frame bundle", but from your comment I think these are different things, right? Sorry if this is very basic, I'm a beginner with spin structures (as you probably noticed).

Comment: Given a principal $SO_n$-bundle $P\rightarrow X$ with $w_2(P)=0$, a spin structure on $P$ consists of a principal $Spin_n$-bundle $\widetilde P\rightarrow X$ and certain [extra structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure). Notable $\widetilde P$ can be the trivial bundle, but the extra structure can be non-trivial.

Comment: As an example, consider the trivial $SO_3$ bundle $P=\mathbb{R}P^4\times SO_3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^4$. There are $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^4;\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ many spin structures on $P$. One is the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}P^4\times Spin_3$ with the obvious fibrewise double covering of $P$. The other is represented by a non-trivial $Spin_3$-bundle.

Comment: It's more natural for me to view things this way: think of a principal $SO_n$-bundle in terms of a fixed classifying map $f:X\rightarrow BSO_n$. The bundle admits a spin structure iff $f^*w_2=0$. A spin structure is then a fibre-homotopy class of lift of $f$ through the map $B\pi:BSpin_n\rightarrow BSO_n$. If $f$ is null-homotopic, then there can be different *fibre*-homotopy classes of lifts which all represent the trivial map $X\rightarrow BSpin_n$. On the other hand, there can be lifts $X\rightarrow BSpin_n$ which are non null-homotopic, but become so after composing with $B\pi$ (see above)